# Will Grass GIS 6s atmospheric correction take raster as input for atmospheric parameters

Tags: grass-gis, atmospheric-correction, grass-6.4

I am working on atmospheric correction using 6s in `Grass 6.4.4` version(i.atcorr module).

I want to use raster data set for atmospheric parameters. Presently I am creating an `icnd` (input condition)file having the atmospheric parameters in a format mentioned in grass help (please check https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.atcorr.html).

But for accurate surface reflectance product one should use raster data (example like MODIS OMI-Aura_L3-OMTO3e_2014m0228_v003-2014m0304t144005.he5.nc )containing atmospheric parameters such as optical depth, water-vapor, ozone for any image.

Is it possible in Grass or do we have to use point data only for aerosols?

Comment: GRASS 7 takes a visibility map as input. But, AFAIK the optical depth, ozone and water vapor are expected to be pretty constant over an area of a few 100 km, at the hour and date of the image.

Comment: can it be customized to take input as raster for that or is it fixed to point parameters only